# How to get data out of websocket autobahnpython

Tags: python-2.7, autobahn

Hi I'm using autobahnpython which connects to a websocket and retrieves the data but I'm struggling to get the data out. Basically I want to use Queues to send the data out to another consumer thread that works on the data itself. The examples I found, only print the received data to stdout or generate some random numbers which they send to the socket. Here is the error I'm getting

```
2014-12-28 18:07:04+0100 [-]     factory.protocol.set_ask_order_queue(Cryptsy_ask_Queue)
2014-12-28 18:07:04+0100 [-] TypeError: unbound method set_ask_order_queue() must be called 
with Cryptsy_socket instance as first argument (got LifoQueue instance instead)
```

Here is my WebSocketClientProtocol derived class:

```
import json
from decimal import *
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import  WebSocketClientProtocol
import time


class Cryptsy_socket(WebSocketClientProtocol):
    _ask_order_queue = []
    _bid_order_queue = []
    _old_bid_order = {}
    _old_ask_order = {}
    _bid_order = {}
    _ask_order = {}


def set_ask_order_queue(self,queue):
    self._ask_order_queue = queue

def set_bid_order_queue(self,queue):
    self._bid_order_queue = queue

def onOpen(self):
    #subscribe for ltc/btc
    self.sendMessage(u"{\"event\": \"pusher:subscribe\",\"data\": {\"channel\": \"ticker.3\"}}".encode("utf8"))

def onConnect(self,response):
    print ("Server connectred: {0}".format(response.peer))

def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):

    print("Text message received: {0}".format(payload.decode('utf8')))


    json_receive = json.loads(payload.decode('utf8'))

    if "event" in json_receive:
        if "message" in json_receive["event"]:
            json_data = json.loads(json_receive["data"])
            buy_order = json_data["trade"]["topbuy"]
            sell_order = json_data["trade"]["topsell"]

            sell_order_price_as_decimal = Decimal(sell_order["price"])
            sell_order_amount_as_decimal = Decimal(sell_order["quantity"])
            sell_order_quote_currency_amount = sell_order_price_as_decimal*sell_order_amount_as_decimal  

            ask_as_decimal = {"price" : sell_order_price_as_decimal,\
                              "amount": sell_order_amount_as_decimal,\
                              "amount_of_second_currency": sell_order_quote_currency_amount,\
                              "name_of_exchange" : "Cryptsy",\
                              "fee_in_percent"  : Decimal("0.25")}

            buy_order_price_as_decimal = Decimal(buy_order["price"])
            buy_order_amount_as_decimal = Decimal(buy_order["quantity"])
            buy_order_quote_currency_amount = buy_order_price_as_decimal*buy_order_amount_as_decimal

            bid_as_decimal = {"price" : buy_order_price_as_decimal,\
                              "amount" : buy_order_amount_as_decimal,\
                              "amount_of_second_currency" : buy_order_quote_currency_amount,\
                              "name_of_exchange" : "Cryptsy",\
                              "fee_in_percent" : Decimal("0.25")}

            self._bid_order["order"] = bid_as_decimal
            self._ask_order["order"] = ask_as_decimal


            if self._old_ask_order == {} or \
                self._ask_order["order"]["price"] != self._old_ask_order["order"]["price"] or\
                self._ask_order["order"]["amount"] != self._old_ask_order["order"]["amount"]:

                ask_order_for_consumer = self._old_ask_order
                ask_order_for_consumer["time"] = time.time()
                self._ask_order_queue.put(ask_order_for_consumer)
                self._old_ask_order = self._ask_order

            if self._old_bid_order == {} or \
                self._bid_order["order"]["price"] != self._old_bid_order["order"]["price"] or\
                self._bid_order["order"]["amount"] != self._old_bid_order["order"]["amount"]:

                bid_order_for_consumer = self._old_bid_order
                bid_order_for_consumer["time"] = time.time()
                self._bid_order_queue.put(bid_order_for_consumer)
                self._old_bid_order = self._bid_order
```

And here is my main which creates the queues and connects, here you can see my problem.
The Cryptsy_socket constructor is not called here thats why I get an error when I try to call set_ask_order_queue and set_bid_order_queue.

```
import sys
from thread_handling.websocket_process_orders import Cryptsy_socket

from twisted.python import log
from twisted.internet import reactor, ssl
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import  WebSocketClientFactory, \
                                    connectWS

import Queue


if __name__ == '__main__':

    Cryptsy_ask_Queue = Queue.LifoQueue()
    Cryptsy_bid_Queue = Queue.LifoQueue()
    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
    factory = WebSocketClientFactory("wss://ws.pusherapp.com:443/app/cb65d0a7a72cd94adf1f?client=PythonPusherClient&version=0.2.0&protocol=6")
    factory.protocol = Cryptsy_socket
    factory.protocol.set_ask_order_queue(Cryptsy_ask_Queue)
    factory.protocol.set_bid_order_queue(Cryptsy_bid_Queue)

    ## SSL client context: default
    ##
    if factory.isSecure:
        contextFactory = ssl.ClientContextFactory()
    else:
        contextFactory = None

connectWS(factory, contextFactory)
reactor.run()
```

So how to accomplish getting data out with a queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found an answer in an old post, where a queue is added to communicate with other threads, which is exactly what I was looking for. 
[override websocketclientprotocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740987/override-autobahn-twisted-websocketclientprotocol-class)